# Dynamic input Field calculate subtotal and grand total

Tags: jquery

Dynamic Input price,tax rate and subtotal display in each row.
sum of subtotal display in subtotal field
when we type display subtract discount

Fiddle works 1st row tax calculation. when add new field dynamically tax rate calculation not working properly.

http://jsfiddle.net/vXHa6/12/

```
$(function () {
    // Append Invoice Line
    $(document).on('click', '#addnewitem', function () {
        var currentTable = $(this).closest('table').attr('id');
        $('#' + currentTable ).append('<tr><td><div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-12">                <input type="Client Name" class="form-control" id="item_price" placeholder="Item Price" name="item_price"></div></td><td><div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-12"><select name="tax" class="form-control" id="tax"><option value="0">None</option><option value="12.5">(12.5%) Service Tax </option></select></div></td><td><div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-12"><input type="Client Name" class="form-control price" id="item_tax" placeholder="Tax Amount"  name="item_tax"></div></td><td><div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-12"><input type="Client Name" class="form-control price" id="sub_total" placeholder="Sub Total"  name="sub_total[]"></div></td><td><button type="button" id="removeItem" class="btn btn-default removeItem" value="-"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash">DELETE</span></td></tr>');
    });  

    //Remove Invoice Line
    $(document).on('click', '#removeItem', function () { 
        var currentTable = $(this).closest('table').attr('id');
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        calculateTableSum(currentTable);
        calculateTotal();
    });

    function calculateSum() {
        var currentTable = $(this).closest('table').attr('id');
        calculateTableSum(currentTable);
    }

    function calculateTableSum(currentTable) {
        var sum = 0;
        $('#' + currentTable + ' input#sub_total').each(function() {
            //add only if the value is number
            if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
                sum += parseFloat(this.value);
            }
        });
        //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
        $('#' + currentTable + ' input.sumamtcollected').val(sum.toFixed(2));
    }

    $(document).on('change', 'input#sub_total', calculateSum);

    $('#tax').on('change', function () { 
        var currentTable = $(this).closest('table').attr('id');
        var itemprice = $('#item_price').val();
        var  taxrate = $('#tax').val();       
        var tax =   taxrate * itemprice /100;
        var total = parseFloat(itemprice) + parseFloat(tax);

         $('#item_tax').val(tax.toFixed(2));
         $('#sub_total').val(total.toFixed(2));
         calculateTableSum(currentTable);
         calculateTotal();
    });    
});
```

Comment: You're creating duplicate IDs. IDs have to be unique. You should use classes for all the recurring elements, not IDs.

Comment: can u please edit in a fiddle

Comment: Sorry, this requires a significant amount of rewriting and I don't have the time right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First problem** : you create several elements with the same ID. Use classes instead of ID. (The concerned elements are all the elements you add with your "Add" button). You **should never assign the same id to more than one element**.

**Second problem** : you're not assigning the `change` callback to the newly added input. Do something like this :

```
var onChangeCallback = function () { 
   var currentTable = $(this).closest('table').attr('id');
   var itemprice = $('.item_price').val();
   var  taxrate = $('.tax').val();

   var tax = taxrate * itemprice /100;
   var total = parseFloat(itemprice) + parseFloat(tax);

    $('.item_tax').val(tax.toFixed(2));
    $('.sub_total').val(total.toFixed(2));
    calculateTableSum(currentTable);
    calculateTotal();
};

$('.tax').on('change', onChangeCallback);
```

And in your click handler :

```
$(document).on('click', '#addnewitem', function () {
      var currentTable = $(this).closest('table').attr('id');
      $('#' + currentTable ).append('A LOT OF HTML TO REWRITE WITH CLASSES INSTEAD OF IDS');
      $('.tax').on('change', onChangeCallback); // this line must be added
});
```

And once you've done that, you'll be facing a **third problem** : the fact that the `onChangeCallback` function uses general selectors such as `$('.item_price')`. This will have the effect of changing the value of **all your fields**, instead of changing only one field. You can try using `.closest()` or `parent()` to workaround this problem.

Hope this helps but I think there is a good amount of rewriting to do. Tell me if you run into troubles, I'll try to help you.

**Edit:** As I told you I would help you, here is a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vXHa6/13/

**However, you should spend time to do this work yourself to understand what your mistakes were and only use my fiddle as a "possible solution". Moreover, by doing the work yourself, you will run into more problems, you'll learn more things and you'll end up with a better solution than mine.**

Comment: @user2154027 You got an answer, and that's what you should be looking for here, not someone to do the work for you.

Comment: I added a working fiddle, you can use it as a "possible solution" for your problem. I created it following the steps I mentionned in my post. However, as @MelanciaUK said : you had your answer, you shouldn't be looking for premade work.